# Alternating Columns of 2 SQL Queries

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I have an oracle query that gets data from two different tables, displaying them as:

```
Project | 20151 | 20152 | 20153 | 20154 | Project_1 | 20151_1 | 20152_1 | 20153_1 | 20154_1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This does get the correct data for what I need, however I need a way of alternating the columns from each of the tables.  E.g:

```
Project | Project_1 | 20151 | 20151_1 | ...
---------------------------------------
```

The query I have is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT planned.YEAR || planned.MONTH as AAA, planned.DAYS as Amount, PROJ.NAME AS Project 
    FROM PLANNED_RESOURCE_TAB planned, USER_LINK_VIEW PROJ
    WHERE ACTUAL.U_P_LINK = PROJ.ID 
    AND PROJ.USER_ID = '1' 
  ) 
  PIVOT
  ( 
    SUM(Amount) FOR AAA in (20151,20152,20153,20154)
  )
) 
PLANNED__ RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT ACTUAL.YEAR || ACTUAL.MONTH as BBB, ACTUAL.DAYS as Amount, PROJ.NAME AS Project 
    FROM ACTUAL_RESOURCE_TAB actual, USER_LINK_VIEW PROJ
    WHERE ACTUAL.U_P_LINK = PROJ.ID 
    AND PROJ.USER_ID = '1' 
  )
  PIVOT
  ( 
    SUM(Amount) FOR BBB in (20151,20152,20153,20154)
  ) 
)ACTUAL__
ON PLANNED__.PROJECT = ACTUAL__.PROJECT
```

The data results will be displayed on a ASP.NET page, so if it is best to manipulate the columns on the page itself that is no problem. I mainly want to know whether it is possible to do it with SQL beforehand, and subsequently how I'd go about that.

The columns cannot be declared in the very first select statement, they will vary dependent on a users input.  The values that are inside the pivot are just for my testing purposes, they will be generated dynamically from the ASP.NET page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It kind of *belongs* on the page. SQL isn't really designed for data presentation, just for data querying. Do the presentation on the presentation layer.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your feedback.  Is that purely for purpose of maintaining a structure to the work, or does it actually optimise as well?

Comment: Well, the purpose is not to "optimise performance" (in some cases it helps, in some cases it hurts, and in others it doesn't matter). It's all about doing things where they fit - if you find that there's a performance critical optimisation you need, you can always break all the patterns (in some reasonable way). For example, it's perfectly legitimate to let the DB only return the first 10 characters of a string if that's all you're going to need on the presentation (or BL), but it doesn't make sense to format a datetime value in SQL, or to name columns using UI titles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace the `*` with the retrieved columns of the most outer select? Something like this:

```
SELECT PLANNED__.Project,
  ACTUAL__.Project,
  PLANNED__."20151",
  ACTUAL__."20151",
  PLANNED__."20152",
  ACTUAL__."20152",
  PLANNED__."20153",
  ACTUAL__."20153",
  PLANNED__."20154",
  ACTUAL__."20154"
FROM
  (SELECT *
  FROM
    (SELECT planned.YEAR
      || planned.MONTH AS AAA,
      planned.DAYS     AS Amount,
      PROJ.NAME        AS Project
    FROM PLANNED_RESOURCE_TAB planned,
      USER_LINK_VIEW PROJ
    WHERE ACTUAL.U_P_LINK          = PROJ.ID
    AND PROJ.USER_ID               = '1'
    ) PIVOT ( SUM(Amount) FOR AAA IN (20151,20152,20153,20154) )
  ) PLANNED__
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT *
  FROM
    (SELECT ACTUAL.YEAR
      || ACTUAL.MONTH AS BBB,
      ACTUAL.DAYS     AS Amount,
      PROJ.NAME       AS Project
    FROM ACTUAL_RESOURCE_TAB actual,
      USER_LINK_VIEW PROJ
    WHERE ACTUAL.U_P_LINK          = PROJ.ID
    AND PROJ.USER_ID               = '1'
    ) PIVOT ( SUM(Amount) FOR BBB IN (20151,20152,20153,20154) )
  )ACTUAL__
ON PLANNED__.PROJECT = ACTUAL__.PROJECT
```

Comment: That does give the exact structure that I want, but the problem is the columns will be changing.  They represent dates, so for instance if a user wanted to see between June 2014 and December 2014, the columns would need to be 20146, 20147 etc. I suppose I could build the query string with C# though, and effectively create your answer that way... Thanks though!